# How to add condition in linq lambda expression

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I add a condition to this datatable count, where it only returns results if `count` is null or has some value?

```
DataTable count = dtAll.AsEnumerable().
     Where(row => row.Field<Int32>("parentCategory") == 0).
     CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: if(count.Rows.Count >0 ) { DO YOUR STUFF HERE }

Comment: i want to add condition before the "copytodatatable" . if there is no value in parentCatagory it throws a error so i need to validate it if any value is there it should copytodata table or else ....

Comment: Formatted code to make it more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way where i can get the count of `dtAll.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field("parentCategory") == 0);`

You can use either [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
DataTable count =  new DataTable();
var res = dtAll.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field("parentCategory") ==  0);
```

For example:

```
if(res.Count() > 0)
{
  count = res.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

or

```
if(res.Any())
{
  count = res.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

I prefer using `Any()` simply because it already returns a boolean.

Comment: If this works for you please consider [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).